# My entity data model wizard is not showing new tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress, entities

I've created a database from scripts using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 and generated some classes in C# using Entity Framework. Now I've had to modify and add a number of new items to that database, including stored procedures and new tables.

However, on trying to regenerate the classes in Visual Studio 2019, the Entity Data Model Wizard is still showing the old database (the way it looked a week ago), including some tables I deleted. None of the new stuff is listed. I've tried deleting and recreating the database, restarting both programs, and restarting the PC to no effect.

The steps I'm taking to generate the framework in Visual Studio are:

- Add a new item to the project.
- Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model.
- Select Code First from database.
- Select Next (the connection string is already filled in).

The next screen is the "Choose Objects and Settings" window, which is where I'm still seeing the old tables (and not the new ones).

Is there some special step I need to take after changing a database to get those changes to show up in Entity Framework?

Comment: Are you looking at the correct database?

Comment: database work just new tables cant found them